# Перезаписывается одна и та же строка в CSV файле

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал вот такой код

```py
from csv import writer

with open('moscow.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as source:
    for line in source.readlines():
        line = line.split(',')
        with open('all.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as base:
            writer_obj = writer(base)
            writer_obj.writerow(line)
```

Вместо того, чтобы добавлять список с новой строки, перезаписывается одна и та же строка. Как это исправить?

Comment: Ну так надо ж открывать не for write, а for append...

Comment: Открывайте файл all.csv один раз до цикла. Сейчас вы постоянно его переоткрываете и перезаписываете его содержимое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открывайте оба файла одновременно. Сейчас вы открываете файл на запись внутри цикла и он перезаписывается на каждой итерации. Ну и `readlines` тут излишне, только лишнюю память съест:

```py
with open('moscow.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as source,
     open('all.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as base:
    writer_obj = writer(base)
    for line in source:
        line = line.split(',')
        writer_obj.writerow(line)
```

Comment: теперь по 2 пустые строки добавляются между нормальными строками с данными

Comment: @Sd1g, при работе через модуль csv нужно открывать файлы с параметром `newline=''`, см. примеры кода для `csv.reader` и `csv.writer` в документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents